# No Resource Found When Import Style ?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle in Android

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, styles

when I try to import the style in my layout for LinearLayout, I always got the error alert "no resource found matches the given name ..." from Eclipse. Is there something wrong with the way that I import the style attribute "?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"? Wait for the clue!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use android's `spinnerDropDownItemStyle`.
Use it this way..

```
style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had issue where my ?attr/ attributes were not being found. Issue was that may dark/night and day/light themes di not match, as far as attr names. This solved my weird issue.